# Could you explain the differences between voiced stop, voiceless unaspirated stop, voiceless aspirated stop?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

Look at this picture for explaining various mechanics of pronunciation with the vocal cords.

[image]

<sub>Source: [wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vot.svg#globalusage)</sub>

I don't understand it much.

Here is what I understood

> -voiced stop: your vocal cord vibrates before you release the air
>
> -voiceless unaspirated stop: your vocal cord vibrates right at the time you release the air
>
> -voiceless aspirated stop: your vocal cord vibrates after the time you release the air

**Could you explain it using simple easy-to-understand language?**

Comment: Very interesting. I've never heard any of those terms, so I can only speculate on the meanings. Looking at the usages, the file is only referenced from zh.wikipedia.org, which appears to be Hong Kong? Out of curiousity, what language are you researching here? Interestingly though, you can search wikipedia for e.g. "voiced plosive" and turn up some [sound files](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?search=voiced+plosive&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&uselang=en), so maybe you can give those a listen and answer it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to consider here: voicing and aspiration.
We make sounds by driving air from the lungs, through the larynx, past the vocal cords and on into the vocal tract.
As the air passes through the larynx, it passes between the vocal cords.
If vocal cords are vibrating as the air enters the  larynx, or start vibrating before the air has finished passing through, the sound produced is *voiced*. Whether it will be a vowel or a plosive depends on what happens next.
If the vocal cords are not vibrating as the air passes through the larynx, the sound is *unvoiced* or *voiceless*.
As the air leaves the larynx, some part of the vocal tract between the larynx and the lips - including the  latter - may momentarily interrupt its passage, partially or completely. If this happens, the resulting sound is called a *plosive*.
So now we can say:
   - - vocal cords not vibrating, air blocked: *voiceless plosive*
- - vocal cords vibrating, air blocked: *voiced plosive*
For simplicity, I will now deal with *stops*, which are a type of plosive.
In English, the voiceless stops are *p,t,k*. Their voiced counterparts are *b,d,g*.
*Aspiration* occurs when the stop is accompanied by a little puff of air following immediately after the stop. In English, this occurs with *initial voiceless stops*, so the *p* in *pin* is aspirated: you hear a slight *h* sound after it. The *p* in *spin* or in *hat-pin* does not have this little puff of air in canonical English speech.
Also in English, voiced stops are never aspirated. They may be in Hindi, though: so *bhai* with aspiration means *brother*, and *bai* without it means *old woman*. And when voiced stops are aspirated, the *h* is usually voiced too, whereas in English *h* is never voiced. 
So the diagram OP shows us is not very useful for describing English. I suspect it's useful for Chinese languages though.

Comment: I would have aspiration on the "p" in "hat-pin." The "p" is at the start of a syllable here. Aspiration would be absent for me in a word like "tap" or "tap-dance."

Comment: I think you would only aspirate in hat-pin in very careful speech. And of course in 'tap' the p is not initial, so no aspiration. But this could lead to a long discussion.